# Data manipulation: gather or spread or both?

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to change my data frame so I can look at it with some different plots. Essentially I want to compare different models. This is what I have:

```
variable = c('A','B','C','A','B','C')
optimal = c(10,20,30,40,80,100)
control = c(15,15,15,15,15,15)
method_1 = c(11,22,28,44,85,95)
method_2 = c(9, 19,31,39,79,102)

df = data.frame(variable, optimal, control, method_1, method_2)
df
```

and so it looks like this:

```
  variable optimal control method_1 method_2
1        A      10      15       11        9
2        B      20      15       22       19
3        C      30      15       28       31
4        A      40      15       44       39
5        B      80      15       85       79
6        C     100      15       95      102
```

And I need something that looks like this:

```
  variable  A  B   C
1  optimal 10 20  30
2  optimal 40 80 100
3  control 15 15  15
4  control 15 15  15
5 method_1 11 22  28
6 method_1 44 85  95
7 method_2  9 19  31
8 method_2 39 79 102
```

I've tried gather and spread and transpose but nothing worked. Any thoughts? Feels that should be a easy fix, but I could not get my head around it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What, *specifically*, have you tried?

Comment: You could also use `melt` and `dcast` from "data.table" like this: `library(data.table); melt(as.data.table(df), "variable", variable.name = "Var")[, dcast(.SD, Var + rowid(variable) ~ variable)]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need both. Also note that `gather` and `spread` has been retired and replaced with `pivot_longer` and `pivot_wider` instead.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -variable) %>%
  group_by(variable) %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = variable, values_from = value) %>%
  select(-row)

#  name         A     B     C
#  <chr>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 optimal     10    20    30
#2 control     15    15    15
#3 method_1    11    22    28
#4 method_2     9    19    31
#5 optimal     40    80   100
#6 control     15    15    15
#7 method_1    44    85    95
#8 method_2    39    79   102
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to go long first and then wide, i.e.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
 pivot_longer(-1) %>% 
 pivot_wider(names_from = variable, values_from = value) %>% 
 unnest()

name         A     B     C
  <chr>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 optimal     10    20    30
2 optimal     40    80   100
3 control     15    15    15
4 control     15    15    15
5 method_1    11    22    28
6 method_1    44    85    95
7 method_2     9    19    31
8 method_2    39    79   102
```

Comment: very nice. to supress the unnest warning use `unnest(cols = everything())`